# centos: fusermount: fuse device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first

Tags: centos, fuse, modprobe

while trying to mount **google bucket** or set **sshfs** up I am getting following error:

```
fusermount: fuse device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
```

*modprobe fuse* command does not show anything:

```
[user@drive ~]# modprobe fuse
[user@drive ~]#
```

fuse is installed

```
[user@drive ~]# yum list installed | grep fuse
fuse.x86_64                           2.9.2-7.el7              @base
fuse-devel.x86_64                     2.9.2-7.el7              @base
fuse-libs.x86_64                      2.9.2-7.el7              @base
fuse-sshfs.x86_64                     2.5-1.el7                @epel
gcsfuse.x86_64                        0.21.0-1                 @gcsfuse
libconfuse.x86_64                     2.7-7.el7                @epel
[user@drive ~]#
```

fuse is not loaded after modprobe

```
[user@drive ~]# lsmod | grep fuse
[user@drive ~]# 
[user@drive ~]# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
[user@drive ~]#
```

installation details

```
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
     CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
          Kernel: Linux 2.6.32-042stab120.19
    Architecture: x86-64
```

Comment: modprobe only prints output on error. Did you try sshfs again after modprobe? Check that the fuse module is loaded in the kernel after modprobe: `lsmod | grep fuse`

Comment: I tried and getting same error. **lsmod | grep fuse** shows nothing. **lsmod** shows nothing too

Comment: Any chance a resolution was found?  I'm stuck on this same issue.

Comment: In my case I had to change VPS provider... This was an issue with the OS image which couldn't be altered to include fuse for whatever reason